# How to add transparency (alpha) as percent in PIL.ImageColor.getcolor?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a function that returns,

```
return "rgba({}%, {}%, {}%, {}%)".format(Percent_1, Percent_2, Percent_3, Alpha)
```

When i put this value in `PIL.ImageColor.getcolor` as in,

```
I.putpixel((J, K), ImageColor.getcolor(RGBAColorFunction(J, K), "RGBA"))
```

I get the following error (for example):

```
ValueError: unknown color specifier: 'rgba(30%, 50%, 70%, 50%)'
```

I have looked to docs but there was no detailed info, neither good examples. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the pixel values without the `%` sign. Change the returns statement from

```
return "rgba({}%, {}%, {}%, {}%)".format(Percent_1, Percent_2, Percent_3, Alpha)
```

to

```
return "rgba({}, {}, {}, {})".format(Percent_1, Percent_2, Percent_3, Alpha)
```

I saw the documentation of `ImageColor` module, and it states that values could be given in percentage, but that is not true.

Upon doing *Source Code Analysis* of the function `getcolor()` it turns out that it calls `getrgb()` in order to get the values of color as a tuple, from the provided string. And `getrgb()` uses Regex for pattern matching the string in order to extract values off from it.

**REGEX USED FOR MATCHING RGBA**:-

```
rgba\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)$
```

it turns out that percentages `%` are not taken into account in this regex, therefore tuple of format equivalent to `rgba(x, x, x, x)` (where `x` is an integer) are only allowed.

**P.S.:-** If you still want to send the output in percentages, you could simply do the math on the values before returning them.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it is the same as your updated answer, which I agree with and have upvoted.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote good questions... it encourages more of them and also gives the OP enough reputation to upvote as well as accept your answer...

Comment: @MarkSetchell T_T sorry Mark. My Bad. Idk why i sometime forget to show appreciation towards other's effort!!

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I solved it with converting percents to 255 cents ;). In other words, %50 = 127 (255 cent) etc. Take a look to my resulting artworks here: [Imgur Gallery](https://imgur.com/gallery/p7ircIx)